# (node:23108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Tags: node.js

(node:23108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

I was caught with this error when is switch to node 14.17.2 from node 20.1.2 for test my another project in node older  version

I released any came to the version which created the project and it worked fine

Comment: If I understand your question, 6 major versions changed, and you expected there to be no errors?

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to [node.green](https://node.green/), support for the Nullish coalescing assignment (`??=`) operator was added in Node.js 15.14.0, and since your code uses it, you cannot run it on Node.js 14.17.2.

You could either use a newer Node.js version, or rewrite your code so it no longer relies on it.